# C++ Object Date but called with only int?

Tags: c++

I have a class Date. The class has 4 private variables (day, hour, min, sec) and all the operator overloading.

Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
map<Date, int> agenda;
```

I want to initialize both end of the agenda. For example:

```
Ressource::Ressource(int qtemin_, int qtemax_, int init_) : qtemin(qtemin_), qtemax(qtemax_) {
// agenda[0] = agenda[2147483647] = init_;
agenda[0] = agenda[Date::last()] = init_;
}
```

instead of :

```
Ressource::Ressource(int qtemin_, int qtemax_, int init_) : qtemin(qtemin_), qtemax(qtemax_) {
// agenda[0] = agenda[2147483647] = init_;
agenda[Date(0,0,0)] = agenda[Date(9999,99,99] = init_;
}
```

That would be my main goal. I know it is possible because I saw someone did it, but I didn't had access to the date.h and date.cpp

The number in the comment is the max int size. (I basically want to do a timeline and initialize both extreme.)

Comment: _"***Somehow, I can't type < > in stackoverflow*"_ Just see the editor help for code formatting, you can type such code prepending four spaces.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then describe the problem you are having. It is not clear to me what you are asking with the little bit of code you gave. It would also be convenient for us to post your effort into a compiler and try any attempts at a solution before getting back to you. We cannot do that with your one liners. I can only guess what Date has in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about defining some static members in your class that return values of interest?

```
class Date {
   // ...
    public static Date last() {
       return Date(9999,99,99);
    }
   // ...
}
```